# when I use log4j 1.2.15, have errors in compile; when change to 1.2.16, everything is fine

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

When using log4j 1.2.15, I have some errors in downloading some other jars. When using log4j 1.2.16, everything is fine. Anyone know why?

Comment: "some errors" - I have never seen "some errors" in my error logs. Errors usually go with error messages ;)

Comment: This is a good thing.  1.2.16 is the more up-to-date version of log4j.  Out with the old and in with the new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oops, I've misread the question.

**Updated answer**

Seems like log4j 1.2.15 has weird dependencies on some of the other artifacts not available in public repository. So you get an error. Please exclude them. I would **strongly** suggest you to use Log4j v1.2.16. The following will do the job for v1.2.15:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
              <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
              <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
              <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
              <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

If you don't really want to exclude. Either manually download the dependencies and install locally or add the following repository:

```
 <repositories>
    ...
    <repository>
      <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
      <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Still, you will have to install `jmxtools` and `jmxri`. I do not think they are available either publicly or on Sun's maven repo.

Comment: Thanks, but still wondeirng why 1.2.16 does not depend on those libraries.

Comment: @user496949 Not sure. But `dependency:tree` shows that v1.2.15 depends on those four artifacts while v1.2.16 depends on none.